# Merge 2 arrays of object and save value in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, merge

Let's have a look at an example.

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    algo: [
      { key: 'c', value: 1 },
      { key: 'java', value: 2 },
    ],
    base: [
      { key: 'js', value: 3 },
      { key: 'python', value: 4 },
    ],
  },
  {
    algo: [
      { key: 'c', value: 10 },
      { key: 'java', value: 20 },
    ],
    base: [
      { key: 'js', value: 30 },
      { key: 'python', value: 40 },
    ],
  },
]
```

I need to merge those 2 arrays of objects and create the following array:

Info: I want to merge the value in an array string/int values
info: I can use lodash

```
const results = [
  {
    algo: [
      { key: 'c', value: [1, 10] },
      { key: 'java', value: [2, 20] },
    ],
    base: [
      { key: 'js', value: [3, 30] },
      { key: 'python', value: [4, 40] },
    ],
  },
]
```

Comment: Please add here your solution too or what you have tried to get to the desired result.

Comment: I've already tried the _.merge and reduce functions

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
const customMerge = (objValue, srcValue) => {
  return { key: objValue.key, value: [objValue.value, srcValue.value] }
}
const mergeAttributes = array => {

  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (Object.keys(acc).length === 0) {
      acc = curr
    } else {
      Object.keys(curr).forEach(key =>
        acc[key] = _.mergeWith(acc[key],curr[key],customMerge)
      )
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```